# Call "create" action of a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a controller, using Rails 3 generator "Controller", and only two actions: create and destroy.

So it generates for me these two lines in routes.rb:

```
get "mycontroller/create"
get "mycontroller/destroy"
```

First I change these action to POST and DELETE verbs:

```
post "mycontroller/create"
delete "mycontroller/destroy"
```

And I'm using jquery to call these actions, like this:

Calling ˜create˜:

```
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "script",
      data:{id: id},
      url: "/mycontroller"
    })
```

but it's not working. I need to put "/create" in the url to work:

```
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "script",
      data:{id: id},
      url: "/mycontroller/create"
    })
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Try in your routes with `post "mycontroller"`

Comment: I got this: Uncaught exception: missing :controller

Comment: It's working now, with:   resources :mycontroller, only: [:create, :destroy]

Comment: My bad. Try with `post "mycontroller", :controller=> 'mycontroller'`

Comment: If you don't know which routes are being generated use `rake routes` for displaying all of them